# Encoding a graph-like physical structure for genetic algorithms

Tags: encoding, box2d, genetic-algorithm

I am looking for research/literature on encoding physical graph-like structures, such as bridges or buildings, as chromosomes for a genetic algorithm.

By graph-like I mean the structure is nodes connected by edges, or for example steel beams connected by welded joints. Research on mutation operators that work on shapes to modify them is also helpful. For these structures, the positions of each joint in space are important, not just the connections themselves.

I am familiar with bitstrings and real-valued encodings. Perhaps there are some similarities to genetic algorithm encodings for neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

Graph structures of neural networks can be adopted to general structures. I just remembered Combining Genetic Algorithms and Neural Networks: The Encoding Problem by Koehn discusses this in 2.2.2 Node-based Encoding and 2.3 Indirect Encoding. Also, the NEAT algorithm fits the problem description nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could find interesting:

**[EVOLUTIONARY DESIGN OF ANALOG ELECTRICAL CIRCUITS USING GENETIC PROGRAMMING](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.917&rep=rep1&type=pdf)**
*(John R. Koza, Forrest H Bennett III, David Andre, Martin A. Keane)*

It describes a genetic programming approach for automatically designing an analog electrical circuit from a high-level statement of the circuit's desired behavior.

The technique is quite general: in the paper it's used to automate the design of both the topology and sizing of the circuit, but it could be adapted to other graph-like problems.

You should change the three original component-creation functions for resistors, capacitors and inductors with steel beams...

The nine ways of changing internal connections can probably be used with minor modifications.

Comment: you might want to know, the link is not serving the intended document.